# Is it possible to alter the HTML in single.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've got a series of images as posts, generated by the loop. As you can [see here](http://herbert-theme.info). Once you click on an image, it takes you to a single post page.

I need to alter the HTML on the **single post** page only. Is this possible?

Comment: please select an answer as correct or rephrase your question so I may further help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  you can.

Here's how WordPress finds which file to use when displaying a single post:

```
single-{post-type}.php > single.php > index.php
```

So, first WP will look in the theme for `single-{post-type}.php`.  Which it will use for a specific type of post.  If no such file exists then it will look for a `single.php`.  Which WP will use for displaying all single posts.  If no such files exists then it will fallback on your `index.php` file to display single posts.

So, either create a `single-{post-type}.php` or a `single.php` and add your modified HTML there.

Answer (score 0):

In your theme files there should be a file named single-post.php. If you open this file with a text editing program you will be able to edit your single post layout.

**BE AWARE**
When you edit this file, all of the pages using single-post.php will be changed as well.

Hope this helps.